# Add multiple elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've created empty array like this:

```
var cars = [];
```

And I'm going to add every car's name and cost. For instance:

```
car[0]["name"] = "BMW";
car[0]["cost"] = 50000;
```

But the problem is, we don't know which index is array dealing with (whether it is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ??).
Every time I should declare new multidimensional array like this:

```
car[] = [];
```

And add two values to it ("**name**" and "**cost**") without knowing which index it has. Appreciate any help guys. If my question looks like ridiculous, sorry for that.

Comment: `car.push({name:"BMW", cost:50000})`

Comment: car[] = {name:"BMW", cost:50000};

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method to insert [Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) instead of creating multidimensional array

```js
var cars = [];
//insert elements like

cars.push({name:"BMW", cost:50000});
cars.push({name:"Ferrari", cost:55000});
// see the cars
console.log(cars)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're wanting to store an array of objects? Like so:

```
[{ name: "BMW", cost: "55222"}, { name: "Toyota", cost: "25222" }]
```

This way you could start off with an empty array and then just push objects to it:

```
var carsArray = []
carsArray.push({ name: "BMW", cost: "55222"}) // Push the BMW to the array
carsArray.push({ name: "Toyota", cost: "25222"}) // Push the Toyota to the array
console.log (carsArray) // This will contain two cars
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking to deal with arrays you either populate or retrieve Values, what i understood is that you wanna know the index so here's a small example:

```
 var cars = [];
```

for population:

```
 cars.push({name:"BMW", cost:50000}); /*Where {name:"BMW", cost:50000} is a new object 
and you can populate it with any parameters and any values*/
```

for value retrieval:

```
for(var i=0;i<cars.length;i++){
   console.log(i);//Here is the index
   console.log(cars[i]);//Here is the value
}
```